# Pont a Dynamically added element to load another element inside

Tags: jquery, html

I created dynamically a div, loaded a bit of code of another html, and loaded it in a static element.

```
var myDiv = document.createElement('div');
$(studentReports).attr('id', 'studentReports');
$(studentReports).load('reports_tables.html .studentReports');

$(reports).append(studentReports);

//The element *reports* is in DOM, has an id="reports"
//among his clases it has the class="reports"
```

At this poitnt, it worked just fine, but when I try to point *student reports* and append even text, it does not work

The methods I tried to use are the following that I searched around here:

```
$('body').find('.studentReports').append( ... );
$('#reports').find('.studentReports').append( ... );
$('.studentReports', '.reports').append( ... );
$('div.reports div.studentReports').append( ... );
```

Comment: Please include your HTML structure, you should show us a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Load takes an optional complete method that will be executed when the load has finished.  To guarantee that the content from the response exists on your page, you would want to do your secondary logic as part of this complete callback logic.  Like...

```
$(myDiv).load('hmlFile.html .dynamicElementClass', function(){
    $('body').find('.dynamicElementClass').append( ... );
});
```